# Why is $I$-$V$ characteristics of a solar cell drawn in the 4th quadrant?

Tags: electric-current, voltage, conventions, electronics, solar-cells

My book says because a solar cell does not draw current but supplies it to the load. I don't quite get the explanation. How is it related?

Comment: This is the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention). It's used in circuit theory to consistently define the sign of current and voltage through a circuit branch. With this convenition if $I\times{}V$ is positive, then power is flowing in to the branch. If $I\times{}V$ is negative, power is flowing out of the branch.

Comment: A handy diagram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current%E2%80%93voltage_characteristic#/media/File:Quadrants_of_IV_plane.svg

Answer (score 2):

The current in other Optoelectric devices like LED and photocells are flowing from a source of voltage to the devices but in case of solar cell, current flows from the cell to the load and thus current in circuit is taken to be in opposite ( or negative direction ). The voltage is still positive. Therefore, the fourth quadrant.

Someone else may provide you with a more explanatory answer.

Answer (score -1):

Actually,in solar cells it do not need current for its operation.It can only supply the current to the load.
At the same time the emf generated by the cell is positive.
So we have a graph on 4th quadrant.

Comment: This post is poorly explained but it does address the question (and, in fact, the existing answer is hardly better). I don't see grounds for deletion here.